# Join "check-constraints" and "check-constraint" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I guess that the tags [check-constraints](/questions/tagged/check-constraints) and [check-constraint](/questions/tagged/check-constraint) should be joined, because they describe the same concept, but one as many, and the other as single. Also, there is a convention or standard for naming tags in singular or plural?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags